# Checking Boost install with MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, boost, mingw

I used the MinGW installation at http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

I ran the second.cpp test found at:
http://tabreziqbal.wordpress.com/2006/03/16/how-to-test-c-boost-installation/
(I used the correct commands to run from the comments, which was
g++ -o second second.cpp -lboost_filesystem)

I get the following error:

C:\Users\user\Projects\Programming\C++\boostTest2>g++ -o second second.cpp -lboost_filesystem
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDlbKGy.o:second.cpp:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_cat
egory()'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDlbKGy.o:second.cpp:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to`boost::system::generic_cat
egory()'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDlbKGy.o:second.cpp:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_cate
gory()'
C:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDlbKGy.o: bad reloc address 0xe in section`.text$_ZN5boost6syst
em14error_categoryD1Ev[__ZN5boost6system14error_categoryD1Ev]'
C:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I know there's an installation test feature of boost that I found on 
http://gcc.gnu.org/testing/testing-boost.html
but those files aren't included with the distribution from nuwen.net (so I'd have to do it myself).

And help is appreciated - I figure I'm just screwing up something minor (I hope anyway).

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not correct command, you should link `boost::system` too (errors are undefined references to `boost::system::system_category`).
Correct command will be `g++ -o second second.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help; I really appreciate it.